# Build error: "Unknown type name 'ffi_cif'"

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, libffi

When building my XCode project, for one of my cocoapod dependencies, libffi, I get 5 build errors, all along the lines of `/Pods/libffi/ios/include/ffi_common.h:77:1: Unknown type name 'ffi_status'`

Any ideas what I could try to debug it? I've already tried cleaning the project.

Comment: Same problem here: libffi (3.0.13)

/Pods/libffi/ios/include/ffi_common.h:78:1: Unknown type name 'ffi_status'
/Pods/libffi/ios/include/ffi_common.h:78:33: Unknown type name 'ffi_cif'
/Pods/libffi/ios/include/ffi_common.h:79:1: Unknown type name 'ffi_status'
/Pods/libffi/ios/include/ffi_common.h:79:37: Unknown type name 'ffi_cif'
/Pods/libffi/ios/include/ffi_common.h:85:3: Unknown type name 'ffi_cif' I found an post on the github of libffi : https://github.com/atgreen/libffi/issues/112

Comment: Are you using BlocksKit? We had that error when using that Pod and stop using it for that reason. Plus it wasn't extremely useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same issue. Xcode 5.1 and Xcode 6.0 GM, both ios device and simulator.
This is also worked for me : http://cameronspickert.com/2014/01/20/remove-the-arm64-architecture-from-cocoapods-targets.html.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem compiling an open source project on iPhone 6 simulator.
Built it for earlier devices and it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

There is an up-to-date solution. The problem is still the same, the 64-bit arch support for some third party library. Add this at the bottom of your Podfile:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |configuration|
      target.build_settings(configuration.name)['ARCHS'] = '$(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)'
    end
  end
end
```

It's a bit different (updated) from the indicated in one of the post above.